# Gigabyte motherboard BIOS version, F3 or F5?

Tags: motherboard, bios, crash, version

My desktop has been experiencing random hard reboots for about 2 weeks (roughly once a day).

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-F2A55M-DS2 v1.0
- CPU: AMD A4-5300
- BIOS version: **F3**, dated 2012-09-28

My question is about the BIOS.

[This info from Gigabyte](https://www.gigabyte.com/Ajax/SupportFunction/GetCpuList?Value=222&SocketValue=380&Socket=AMD%20Socket%20FM2&Chipest=AMD%20A55&Type=Chipest) states *Since BIOS Version* as **F5** for my CPU. I don't know what that means exactly. **Why do I have F3 when this listing states F5?** Does this mean it would be prudent for me to update from F3 to F5?

Comment: Some BIOS updates for some computers included security fixes that Windows 10 needed. It is hard to say whether this is the cause of the reboots. Some computer BIOS upgrades are tricky (my computer offer solid BIOS upgrade apps) so you would need to research whether upgrading BIOS is a good idea for you.

Comment: If your firmware is being as reported as F3, then it’s F3, it’s doubtful upgrading your firmware will resolve a problem that’s recently appeared if your system has been stable since 2012

Comment: I would focus on running a memtest on your RAM, and/or Prime95 on your CPU to soak-test the components. It's highly likely the hard reboots are caused by faulty components, rather than an out-of-date BIOS.

Comment: If a BIOS has worked for nearly 10 years I would not change it now. Better make the basic hardware checks especially the "clean-up test". A 10 year old system is usually covers in dust and dirt and cowebs.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure**, but I think this means that my BIOS version was too stale when it was installed. The *Since BIOS Version* column means, I think, that the given CPU was supported by the BIOS starting with the given BIOS-version.

In my case, I should have received F5 (2013-03-18) when I bought the PC in 2014-03, but I have F3 (2012-09-28) instead.

[Reference for BIOS versions](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-F2A55M-DS2-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late, but, your motherboard is rev 1.0, the F5 update is only for rev 1.2. That said, your **Since BIOS Version** is F2, meaning you are one update ahead.

I'm doubtful of mine thought, i have:

- GA-H81M-H rev 1.1
- I3-4150

My bios is F5 but in the gigabyte info, it says it's F7, now i don't know if i need to update it or not. People say it's not needed if your pc is working normally, but i keep feeling if i update my bios, maybe i could tweak better my settings and get better performance.